# AS3 Play movie clip and navigate to another frame on the main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a button that you hover over that sits on one frame - it goes with the movie clip that sits on the very next frame ( both of these are in the same key frame ) and plays it on frame 134. After that movie clip has played, I would like the timeline to take you to the next frame.

I can not use this:

```
stop(); 
if( MovieClip(root).currentFrame < MovieClip(root).totalFrames ) {
    MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}
```

I have tried to put that code in the last frame of the mc, but it won't work.

Right now even with the stop command it still loops.

Comment: where is the movieclip?

Comment: What frame is your code located in?

Comment: it is in the last frame of the movie clip

Comment: I'd suggest a simple parent.play() on the last frame of your mc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `this.parent` instead of `root` like so,

```
stop(); 

if(MovieClip(this.parent).currentFrame < MovieClip(this.parent).totalFrames)
{  
    MovieClip(this.parent).nextFrame(); 
}
```

Best luck.